# How to add multiple values to a key in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, function, debugging, local-storage

Im trying to allow a user to select multiple select options that can be stored in local storage.
Trying to allow users to choose multiple select options that get saved and are displayed on screen.

html

```
   <body>
    <div class="custom_tunings">
        <h1>Custom Tunings</h1>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add New Tunings</legend>
            <div class="formBox">
                <label for="">Tuning Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="inpkey" placeholder="Insert Name"> <br>
            </div>
            <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
                <div class="formBox">
                    <select class="mynoteslist" id="inpvalue">
                        <option value="A1">A1</option>
                        <option value="B1">B1</option>
                        <option value="C1">C1</option>
                        <option value="D1">D1</option>
                        <option value="E1">E1</option>
                        <option value="F1">F1</option>
                        <option value="G1">G1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="formBox">
                    <select class="mynoteslist" id="inpvalue2">
                        <option value="A1">A1</option>
                        <option value="B1">B1</option>
                        <option value="C1">C1</option>
                        <option value="D1">D1</option>
                        <option value="E1">E1</option>
                        <option value="F1">F1</option>
                        <option value="G1">G1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
            <button type="button" id="btninsert">Save Tuning </button>
            <br>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>My Tunings</legend>
            <div id="isoutput"> </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Im trying add multiple inpvalues to a key.
I cant seem to add another inpvalue as it seems to only accept the first value.
Im wondering if theres a simple way around this?

javascript

```
let inpkey = document.getElementById("inpkey");
let inpvalue=document.getElementById("inpvalue");
//let inpvalue2=document.getElementById("inpvalue2");



let btninsert = document.getElementById("btninsert");
let isoutput = document.getElementById("isoutput");

btninsert.onclick = function(){
  let key = inpkey.value;
  let value = inpvalue.value;
  //let value2 = inpvalue.value;

  console.log(key);
  console.log(value);
//console.log(value2);

  if(key && value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key,value);
    location.reload();
  }
};
for(let i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++){
  let key=localStorage.key(i);
  let value=localStorage.getItem(key);



  isoutput.innerHTML += `${key}: ${value}  <br>` ;
}
```

the desired output would be something like this
Howver if i try to select different options it only takes the first value and applies them to all.

[image]

Comment: Each localStorage key stores a single string value.  If you want, that value can be a JSON representation of an array of values, but you have to maintain adding to that array yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for the existence of a key and if found, append the new value to the existing value before saving.

```
if(key && value) {

    // if the key exists
    if(localStorage.getItem(key)){  

        // split the existing values into an array
        let vals = localStorage.getItem(key).split(','); 

        // if the value has not already been added
        if(! vals.includes(value)){ 

            // add the value to the array
            vals.push(value); 

            // sort the array
            vals.sort(); 
            
            // join the values into a delimeted string and store it
            localStorage.setItem(key, vals.join(',')); 
        }      
    }else{
        // the key doesn't exist yet, add it and the new value
        localStorage.setItem(key,value);
    }    
    location.reload();
}
```

I made a working example of the above code here: https://jsfiddle.net/01rjn3cf/2/

**EDIT:** Based on your comments and added example of desired output, I see that you don't want a distinct list of values and that any value can be added to the list of previously selected values.  In this case the solution is even easier..

```
if(key && value) {

    // if the key exists
    if(localStorage.getItem(key)){             
            
        // add this value onto the end of the existing string
        localStorage.setItem(key, localStorage.getItem(key) + ', ' + value); 
              
    }else{
        // the key doesn't exist yet, add it and the new value
        localStorage.setItem(key,value);
    }    
    location.reload();
}
```

**EDIT:**
I modified it as so to work as desired.

```
if(key && value) {
  var content = value + ', ' + value2 + value3;
    // if the key exists
    if(localStorage.getItem(key)){

        // add this value onto the end of the existing string

        localStorage.setItem(key, content);

    }else{
        // the key doesn't exist yet, add it and the new value
        localStorage.setItem(key, content);
    }
    location.reload();
}
};
for(var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++){
  var key=localStorage.key(i);
  var value=localStorage.getItem(key);



  isoutput.innerHTML += `${key}: ${value}  <br>` ;
}
```

Comment: Your code still only displays the first Select input upon saving under "my tunings". Wheras im trying to save multiple. Not just the first one. which is the current issue.

Comment: Your going to have to explain in further detail what you mean by select multiple then

Comment: Maybe my codepen link would help explain https://jsfiddle.net/theodorev/28ofjamb/?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have implemented @Drew's fix to store a list of items, you will need to supply all of the values of the selects.

Rather than

```
btninsert.onclick = function(){
  let key = inpkey.value;
  let value = inpvalue.value;
  //let value2 = inpvalue.value;
  ...
```

You'll need all of the selects, and then pass each one into the localStorage part.  Here I find all the select elements with class "mynoteslist", get their values, then filter out the empty ones

```
btninsert.onclick = function(){
  let key = inpkey.value;

  const inpValues = [...document.querySelectorAll("select.mynoteslist")]
    .map({value} => value)
    .filter(value => value);

  if (inpValues.length) {
    inpValues.forEach(v => storeLocally(key, v));
    location.reload();
  }
  //...
```

Then @Drew's part wrapped in a function

```
function storeLocally(key, value) {

    if(key && value) {

        // if the key exists
        if(localStorage.getItem(key)){  

            // split the existing values into an array
            let vals = localStorage.getItem(key).split(','); 

            // if the value has not already been added
            if(! vals.includes(value)){ 

                // add the value to the array
                vals.push(value); 

                // sort the array
                vals.sort(); 
                
                // join the values into a delimeted string and store it
                localStorage.setItem(key, vals.join(',')); 
            }      
        }else{
            // the key doesn't exist yet, add it and the new value
            localStorage.setItem(key,value);
        }    
    }
}
```